# Error creating database in Cloudera Impala (Virtual machine)

Tags: centos, cloudera, impala, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have downloaded and started the cloudera virtual machine with impala. At the time of executing the database creation statement, an error related to the catalog and state-store service appeared. Perform the service update from console, however when trying to create a database the following message appears

```
Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050',)
```

I have restarted the following services, but the problem persists: impala-catalog impala-state-store impala-server

Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Can you resolve `quickstart.cloudera` host name from where you're running the command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved alone. Apparently the virtual machine takes longer than I expected to start all services. Once I let it start and wait for a reasonable time, it worked without problems.